# positions for list view in android development

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to get the position of a list view in android development. I am wanting to get the position value and save it into a pref file. The code I have is

```
public class Browse extends Activity {

private ListView mainListView;  
private ArrayAdapter<Card> listAdapter; 
public static final String userPrefs = "UserPrefs";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView);  

    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    // Remember to drop existing table if it exists
    dh.removeAll();

    // Insert 4 Lecturers into the database
    Log.d("Database: ", "Inserting values..");
    dh.addCard(new Card(1, "Katniss Evergreen", "11", "33", "55", "44",     R.drawable.katniss));
    dh.addCard(new Card(2, "Peeta Melark", "49", "44", "11", "65", R.drawable.peeta));
    dh.addCard(new Card(3, "Gale Hawthrone", "87", "32", "98", "50", R.drawable.gale));
    dh.addCard(new Card(4, "Haymitch", "30", "32", "45", "31", R.drawable.haymitch));
    dh.addCard(new Card(5, "Effie Trinket", "65", "54", "21", "34", R.drawable.effie));
    dh.addCard(new Card(6, "President Snow", "23", "45", "67", "21", R.drawable.snow));

    List<Card> list = dh.getAll();  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the list of lecturers
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Card>(this, R.layout.simplerow, list);

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  

    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String value = mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        SharedPreferences sp;
        sp = getSharedPreferences(userPrefs, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("name", value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    }); 



}



}
```

This works but it saves the actual name, so if I click Katniss Evergreen it will save the name "Katniss Evergreen". I don't want this I want the position value so like 1 for Katniss, 2 for Peeta etc. Any one know how I can do this? I have been working all weekend on this and just can't get my head around it :( i'm fairly new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want get position from list or value from Card object ?

If from list than you had `position` parameter passed to `onClick`.

Otherwise, try get `Card` object and get value from it.

```java
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    Card card  = (Card) mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    int value = card.getId(); // Or other method

    SharedPreferences sp;
    sp = getSharedPreferences(userPrefs, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("name", value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to save the position as a number parsed into string use:

```
    String pos = Integer.toString(position);
```